# Can someone spot an calculated column error Please?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, calculated-column, site-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a calculated column where 'Today Date' is another date column. The first two block are working fine till the [Enter time]=2 condition when I add other two it says syntax error.

```
IF( ([Enter Time]="1")
    ,([Today Date]+365)
    ,(IF(
          ([Enter Time]="2")
          ,([Today Date]+730)
         )
     ),(IF([Enter Time]="3"),([Today Date]+1095))),(IF(([Enter Time]="2"),([Today Date]+1460))))
```

Comment: I reformatted your formula with linebreaks and spaces.. and stopped when you obviously went wrong with the ( )  notation.. Tip: do this in a decent texteditor then copy paste your formula to SP, it will remove all linebreaks and unneeded spaces

Comment: If you use Named-Cells in Excel you can also prepare your Formula in Excel and make it work in Excel first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this condition

```
IF([Enter Time]="1",[Today Date]+365,IF([Enter Time]="2",[Today Date]+730,IF([Enter Time]="3",[Today Date]+1095,IF([Enter Time]="4",[Today Date]+1460))))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Enter Time]="2" is checked twice

IF([Enter Time]="1",[Today Date]+365,IF(**[Enter Time]="2"**,[Today Date]+730,IF([Enter Time]="3",[Today Date]+1095,IF(**[Enter Time]="2"**,[Today Date]+1460)))

Comment: Thanks for replying Monica, but I tried it is still throwing error. I believe I missing some brackets but not sure where?